# Infinity execution for SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have execute this query

```
select * from tPartMasterEx
```

However, the query keep on execute, and there is no data display, I check the deadlock,but didn't found any.

Is there any way to stop this infinity execution? Maybe I should do some query to stop this,or hard kill it?
Can someone please help me?Thanks

Comment: How long does it just keep running? How much data do you have in this table?

Comment: Which storage engine your schema is using? Try run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` for the running threads.Check if there is any locks .

Comment: As others have pointed out, the query can take a long time to execute dependent on the amount of rows that you have. Try `select count(1) from tPartMasterEx` to find out how many rows there are. Dependent of your DBMS (hard to tell since you did not tag it) there may be ways to find out whether it is working with your query.

Comment: its a fresh new table i created, so when i checked,its only 4 rows exist.

Comment: @Lennart,i just try insert data from the application,and when i run the select count,the execution is still never ending.

Comment: Your application probably did not commit the insert, that's why you can't see the rows in another connection. What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try running below commands if you explicitly want to kill the query.

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; // Get the process ID. p_id.
Kill p_id;
```

Also Look for the `Slow Query Log` to know the actually reason behind slowness.

Comment: Do you even know what is going on here? why rush to answer?

Comment: Check what he said. he wrote "Maybe I should do some query to stop this,or hard kill it" .Thats why i answered how to kill the running thread. I will delete my answer if this is not what he is looking for.

Comment: Hi,i do want to kill the never ending execute query.since it never stop. And i try run the SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST, but i get an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FULL'.'

Comment: @AmanMJ try `sp_who` or `sp_who2` for sql server. Previous command was for MySql actually.